# How can I accelerate this MySQL query?

Tags: performance, mysql, query-optimization

```
geneHomology
============
id genome_name  gene_id  homolog_genome_name  homolog_gene_id consider_homolog
1  HomoSap      1007     MusMus               824             1
2  HomoSap      1007     MusMus               825             1
3  HomoSap      1007     MusMus               826             1
4  HomoSap      2890     EColi                2140            1
...

gene
====
genome_name  gene_id  gene_category
MusMus       823      Upregulated
MusMus       824      Downregulated
MusMus       825      Normal
MusMus       826      Normal
MusMus       827      Upregulated
EColi        2140     Normal
...
```

`consider_homolog` is an enum (0,1). `genome_name` and `gene_id` are primary keys in `gene`. `geneHomology` is very large - some 200M rows.

My goal is to count for each gene in `genes` how many homologs it has from each `gene_category`.

For example, following the data above, `HomoSap 1007` has 3 `Normal` homologs and 1 `Downregulated`.

So my query is:

```
SELECT a.id,a.genome_name,a.gene_id,a.homolog_genome_name,a.homolog_gene_id,COUNT(b.gene_category)
FROM geneHomology a,gene b 
WHERE a.consider_homolog='1' AND a.homolog_genome_name=b.genome_name AND a.homolog_gene_id=b.gene_id 
GROUP BY a.genome_name,a.gene_id,b.gene_category;
```

It never returns (and I've been patiently waiting for more than an hour).

I already indexed `gene_category` in `gene`.

I'm really new to MySQL but I have root access to the DB so I could follow your suggestions (carefully...). I would be happy to provide any further information.

**UPDATE**
This is the `EXPLAIN` output for the query:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+-----------------------+----------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys         | key                  | key_len | ref                                                      | rows    | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+-------+------+-----------------------+----------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | b     | ALL  | PRIMARY,gene_genome   | NULL                 | NULL    | NULL                                                     | 1560695 | Using temporary; Using filesort | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | ref  | geneHomologyHit_gene  | geneHomologyHit_gene | 54      | my_db_v71.b.gene_id,my_db_v71.b.genome_name              |      13 | Using where                     | 
+----+-------------+-------+------+-----------------------+----------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------------------------------+
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
mysql> SHOW INDEX FROM gene;
    +-------+------------+--------------------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
    | Table | Non_unique | Key_name                 | Seq_in_index | Column_name         | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
    +-------+------------+--------------------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
    | gene  |          0 | PRIMARY                  |            1 | gene_id             | A         |        NULL |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         | 
    | gene  |          0 | PRIMARY                  |            2 | genome_name         | A         |     1560695 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         | 
    | gene  |          1 | gene_organism            |            1 | taxon_id            | A         |         392 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         | 
    | gene  |          1 | gene_genome              |            1 | genome_name         | A         |         853 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         | 
    | gene  |          1 | gene_gene_category       |            1 | gene_category       | A         |           5 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         | 
    +-------+------------+--------------------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
    5 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

**UPDATE 3**

```
mysql> SHOW INDEX FROM geneHomology;
+--------------+------------+------------------------+--------------+--------------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table        | Non_unique | Key_name               | Seq_in_index | Column_name              | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+--------------+------------+------------------------+--------------+--------------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| geneHomology |          0 | PRIMARY                |            1 | id                       | A         |   680326661 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         | 
| geneHomology |          1 | geneHomologyQuery_gene |            1 | gene_id                  | A         |     1498516 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         | 
| geneHomology |          1 | geneHomologyQuery_gene |            2 | genome_name              | A         |     1505147 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         | 
| geneHomology |          1 | geneHomologyHit_gene   |            1 | homolog_gene_id          | A         |    52332820 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         | 
| geneHomology |          1 | geneHomologyHit_gene   |            2 | homolog_genome_name      | A         |    52332820 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         | 
+--------------+------------+------------------------+--------------+--------------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**UPDATE 4**
Is there a way to get only partial results to even see I'm getting what I want? I tried `LIMIT 1000` and even `LIMIT 10` but it doesn't seem to change anything.

**UPDATE 5**

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE geneHomology;
+--------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table        | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
+--------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| geneHomology | CREATE TABLE `geneHomology` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `genome_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `gene_id` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `homolog_genome_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `homolog_gene_id` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `homolog_length` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `significance` double unsigned NOT NULL,
  `bit_score` double unsigned NOT NULL,
  `percent_identity` double unsigned NOT NULL,
  `start_match` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `end_match` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `start_match_percent` double unsigned NOT NULL,
  `end_match_percent` double unsigned NOT NULL,
  `strand` enum('+','-') default NULL,
  `homolog_start_match` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `homolog_end_match` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `homolog_start_match_percent` double unsigned NOT NULL,
  `homolog_end_match_percent` double unsigned NOT NULL,
  `homolog_strand` enum('+','-') default NULL,
  `consider_gene_homology` enum('0','1') NOT NULL,
  `reason_not_considered` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `num_hsps` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `homology_type` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `geneHomologygene` (`gene_id`,`genome_name`),
  KEY `geneHomologyhomolog_gene` (`homolog_gene_id`,`homolog_genome_name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=680326662 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 | 
+--------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE gene;
+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| gene  | CREATE TABLE `gene` (
  `taxon_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `genome_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `gene_id` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `symbol` varchar(30) default NULL,
  `type` varchar(30) default NULL,
  `product` varchar(300) default NULL,
  `strand` enum('+','-') NOT NULL,
  `start` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `end` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `gene_category` enum('Upregulated','Downregulated','Normal','n/a') NOT NULL,
  `consider_gene` enum('0','1') NOT NULL,
  `reason_not_considered` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `sequence` longblob NOT NULL,
  `additional_info` varchar(300) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`gene_id`,`genome_name`),
  KEY `gene_organism` (`taxon_id`),
  KEY `gene_genome` (`genome_name`),
  KEY `gene_gene_category` (`gene_category`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 | 
+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: try run explain on your query

Comment: if you use consider_homolog in where clause , try to index this column !

Comment: @Haim Evgi: 1) see update for `explain` 2) I'm indexing it now, but I also tried to run the query without it which didn't seem to help.

Comment: what is this column gene_replicon? its a posibble key on table b, he run over all b table!

Comment: @Haim Evgi: forget `gene_replicon` it's `gene_genome` (I changed some name in the OP to make it more readable, and forgot to change this one. Anyway, now it's updated). I think its one of the indexes for table b. See update 2.

Comment: Just try to make the resultset as small and as indexed as possible with WHERE clause

Comment: Would be good to have full table structures known (SHOW CREATE TABLE...) to analyze this better. I also find the query a bit puzzling, why are you using gene_category both in COUNT and GROUP BY? Aren't possible values for the count then 0 and 1?

Comment: I'm confused. What are hit_genome_name and hit_gene_id?  I don't see them anywhere in the tables as you've given them. Also, we'll need to see the indexes on the geneHomology table to really know what's going on.

Comment: NB If you multiply the values in the rows column of the explain you get a rough idea of the number of rows the DB is evaluating 20,000,000 in this case.

Comment: @beamrider9: you're right. `hit_genome_name` and `hit_gene_id` should be `homolog_genome_name` and `homolog_gene_id`. Sorry for the confusion. I will update the OP.

Comment: @beamrider9: also see update 3.

Comment: @Mikko Wilkman: I want to count how many rows are there for each category. Isn't that the way to that? I wish I could run this query on a small set just to see it's right. I tried `LIMIT 10` but it doesn't help.

Comment: @Jaydee: I have no idea if 20,000,000 is considered a lot or not... :)

Comment: @ David B: Depends on your hardware. If the query hasn't returned after an hour I'd say it's a lot.

Comment: @Jaydee I'm running on a 64bit linux machine with 8 2.6GHz processors and some 16GB RAM. The thing is it doesn't seem it's even sweating (CPU and memory usage are low).

Comment: As far as memory usage is concerned, MySQL has lots of tunable parameters, you may want to increase some of the memory configuration. "geneHomology is very large - some 200M rows"  you don't say how big the record size (or average record size is) , but if it is over 80 Bytes, the table will nto fit in memory  (even smaller in fact because of everything else required in memory) so this is likely to be diskbound anyway. But I still think that denormalisation, by adding the gene_category column (or 1 char identifier) to the geneHomology table would pay dividends with this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.genome_name, a.gene_id,
        cats.gene_category,
        (
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
        FROM    geneHomology ab
        JOIN    gene b
        ON      b.genome_name = ab.homolog_genome_name
                AND b.gene_id = ab.homolog_gene_id
        WHERE   ab.genome_name = a.genome_name
                AND ab.gene_id = a.gene_id
                AND b.gene_category = cats.gene_category
        ) cx
FROM    gene a
CROSS JOIN
        (
        SELECT  'Normal' AS gene_category
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  'Upregulated' AS gene_category
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  'Downregulated' AS gene_category
        ) cats
LIMIT 100
```

This will remove `filesort` from your plan.

If you have a table with all possible `gene_categories`, replace the `cats` with it.

Comment: +1 Thanks, but it says 'ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'ab.gene_id' in 'where clause'.

Comment: @David: could you please post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE geneHomology` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE gene`?

Comment: @Quassnoi: Sure, please see update 5 at the OP. Thanks again for your attention.

Comment: @David: I created the tables and the query parses perfectly on my server. Which `MySQL` version do you use?

Comment: @Quassnoi: My mistake. I probably had some typo earlier. It now works great with a limit as high as 100k. In total, I'm expecting some 1.6M*5=8M rows. With 50k limit it takes 4 sec. With 100k limit - 8.4 sec. With 200k limit - 17 sec. So I figured it should complete the unlimited query in about 11 minutes. However, I'm waiting for more than an hour now and nothing has been printed yet. Any idea?

Comment: @Quassnoi: And I also noted now that something is wrong. I always get only one of the `gene_category` with non-zero in it. It seems its always the one of the itself, so we don't actually count the categories of the homologs but count all the homologs (regardless of their category) in the category of the gene.

Comment: @David: just checked on the data you provided (I added homo genes to the gene `table`). It returns `2` normal, `1` downregulated for `Homo/1007`, `1` normal for `Homo/2890`. Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

From what you've posted here, I would reccomend a minor bit of denormalisation and put gene_category into geneHomolgy. You can then get rid of the join entirely and you can create an index on your consider_homolog + GROUP BY fields.

Answer (score 0):

First remove the reference to genome_name from the WHERE part of the query - if both gene.gene_id and gene.genome_name are unique then here is a clear functional dependency here which is confusing the issue somewhat - the number/number join will be marginally mroe efficient that the text/text join.

Looking at the plan it rather implies you've already got an index on geneHomology.hit_gene_id . If this is the case then there's not much scope for making the query go faster without schema changes. However a key length of 54 suggests you've got a lot of stuff in that index which should not be there. Trimming this down to just hit_gene_id and consider_homolog will help a little with the performance, but the limiting factor is that there does not seem any way to avoid the full table scan on gene unless there are other functional dependencies in there.

How quickly does it take to complete a 'SELECT * FROM gene' ? How many records in ene_homology?

It looks like geneHomology decomposes a N:M relationship between gene and gene (itself) and applies labels.

If the number of values in homolog_genome_name is relatively small you might consider decomposing this into gene using bitmap field. Or possibly denormalise the relationship into a set of 1:1 mappings. Alternatively you could enumerate the homolog clusters.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM gene` returns quite fast but takes a long time to print, since there is a long string which is the sequence of the gene. `SELECT genome_name,gene_id FROM gene;` returns `1560695 rows in set (3.37 sec)`. `homolog_genome_name` has about 850 values. Only a pair of `gene_id` and `genome_name` makes a unique gene key (there are sometimes genes with the same `gene_id` but in different genomes).